# Extending coplanarity of 4 points to 5 or more points.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, 3d

Context: We were taught collinearity of 3 points (in vectors) and a method for checking 4 points for coplanarity simultaneously. Searching around I found a better method for checking for coplanarity in 4 points i.e. the 4x4 determinant.

In a 2d plane there is a 3x3 determinant to check for collinearity of 3 points
In a 3d plane similarly a 4x4 determinant for coplanarity of 4 points
So for 5 points would it have to be a 4d plane? If so how does that work?

There is already a simple way  that I thought of to check for coplanarity in any number points which would be to check $\binom{n}4$ cases of coplanarity many of which are actually not needed for eg: in 5 points you would only need to check 2 cases out of 5 from the 4x4 det and 3 cases out of 10 from the 3x3 det.

So is there a way to check directly (without forming cases) the coplanarity of 5 points in a 3d coordinate system (maybe like a 5x5 determinant?)

Comment: Write up a matrix containing your points. Calculate its [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)). That'll be the dimensionality of the space your points span. E.g. if for $5$ points (in any space) the rank is $2$, then they are all coplanar.

Comment: @Daniel Not quite. The rank of the matrix is 2 when all points lie within a single 2-dimensional subspace, i.e. a single plane **through the origin**.

Comment: @DanielP A way to repair your approach is to add 1 as an extra coordinate to each point.

Comment: What is the reason/proof of this like why does this work ? Also the approach is to write sets of coordinates with an extra column of 1 at the end?